# How to get 'Layout' for a work item type from DevOps API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to fetch layout info for work items.
I'm familiar with the following API 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/layout/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 but I always get the same error back from it, reading
"VS403115:You cannot modify form layout information for work item types ***...*** in process ***...*** as these work item types are locked."

While I understand what the error means, I'm just trying to READ the layout data, rather than modify it.
I did double check that the request is a GET, and I tried different versions of the API (4.x, 5.x)

Comment: We also ran into this issue recently. Seems like a bizarre decision to disallow even GET on default layout templates. Quite regressive to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error is because you are trying to get layout for a default process template. This API is using to get the full work item form layout for a process using **inherited customization**.

If you try to get layout for a inherited process template, you'll get a successful response.

The following link explains this API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/layout?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: To be clear, are you confirming that there's also no alternate way to get the layout for the default process templates?
And if so, what's the best way to make a feature request? Thanks!

Comment: You can submit a suggestion at the website below: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21